# How to save inherited objects in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have implemented inheritance in cakephp . I have two models Person and Employee. Employee inherits Person

```
Person: id, name, age, address
Employee: id, person_id
```

when i do **$this->Employee->savAll($this->request->data)**, Person and Employee are saving but the **person_id is not getting set** in database, Its being filled by NULL, Is there any way to save the inherited objects properly at one shot, The models are shown below

```
Class Person extends AppModel{
 var $name="Person";
}

App::import('model', 'Person')
Class Employee extends Person{
  var $name="Employee";
  public $actsAs = array( 'Inherit' ); 
}
```

Comment: I think you might be mixing inheritance and relations. But I'm not familiar with the InheritableBehavior that you seem to be using. Is it this one by CakeDC? https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/master/Model/Behavior/InheritableBehavior.php

Comment: no, Its proper inheritance, where i was not able to save the person_id  in Employee table.I followed http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/inheritable-behavior-missing-link-of-cake-model article.

Comment: Weird, that link is broken for me, Google Cache only has a (machine) translated german version...

Comment: sorry for that, this is the link    http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/santino83/2011/02/19/behavior_for_model_inheritance_the_missing_feature

Comment: So you may want to define your associations. Employee belongsTo Person .

Comment: Yes, If that is the case then its a weird kind of relation, having inheritance and association, So still cakephp does not fully support inheritance unlike in other JAVA frameworks.

Comment: Setting the bindings (relations) is what the behavior is doing in _initBindings($model)-function. I think you need set the recursion depth in your saveAll

Comment: also, using 2.x dont use app::import, use app::uses instead

Answer (score 0):

From the [Saving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array) docs,

> The saveAll function is just a wrapper around the saveMany and saveAssociated methods

You are saving neither many of one model, nor associated models. You will need to save the parent model, retrieve the ID, and use that to save the inheriting model.